# Conflict between emmet-mode and yasnippet, same trigger key

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, use-package

I want to have both `emmet-mode` and `yasnippet` trigger with the same key <kbd>C-return</kbd>: in a `html-mode` buffer, <kbd>C-return</kbd> should first try `yas-expand` and then `emmet-expand-line` if no suitable snippet was found.

It seems I am missing something about the binding keywords in `use-package`. Currently only `emmet-mode`'s bind is active in a HTML buffer.

#### lisp/init-emmet.el

```el
(use-package emmet-mode
  :defer t
  :init
  (add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
  :config
  (setq-default
   emmet-move-cursor-between-quotes t
   emmet-preview-default nil)
  (unbind-key "C-M-<left>" emmet-mode-keymap)
  (unbind-key "C-M-<right>" emmet-mode-keymap))
```

#### lisp/init-yasnippet.el

```el
(use-package yasnippet
  :defer t
  :bind (:map yas-minor-mode-map ("<C-return>" . yas-expand))
  :init
  (add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  :config
  (setq-default yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"))
  (yas-reload-all)
  (unbind-key "TAB" yas-minor-mode-map))
```

Comment: As an aside, passing a `:map` to `bind-keys*` (including via `:bind*`) doesn't do anything; it will ignore the map argument and bind its keys in `override-global-map`.

Comment: Yes, what I have doesn't actually make sense (mere and futile attempt after many others). So both emmet-mode and yasnippet should have their binds bound to their own map, but how do I set "priority" (?) of one over another?

Comment: Check out https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/minor-mode-hack.el

Comment: Oh dear, someone needs to get that into a publically hosted git repo, and published to MELPA pronto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using `hippie-expand` which is built-in to Emacs (24+?).

#### emmet-mode

```el
(use-package emmet-mode
  :defer t
  :init
  (add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
  :config
  (setq-default emmet-move-cursor-between-quote t)
  (unbind-key "<C-return>" emmet-mode-keymap)
  (unbind-key "C-M-<left>" emmet-mode-keymap)
  (unbind-key "C-M-<right>" emmet-mode-keymap))
```

#### hippie-expand

```el
(use-package hippie-exp
  :ensure nil
  :defer t
  :bind ("<C-return>" . hippie-expand)
  :config
  (setq-default hippie-expand-try-functions-list
                '(yas-hippie-try-expand emmet-expand-line)))
```

#### yasnippet

```el
(use-package yasnippet
  :defer t
  :init
  (add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  :config
  (setq-default yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"))
  (yas-reload-all)
  (unbind-key "TAB" yas-minor-mode-map)
  (unbind-key "<tab>" yas-minor-mode-map))
```